# How to convert SAS data char to date

Tags: sas, data-management

I have char date '31DEC2015' on **SAS Data** set and I need to convert it into **date format**. How can I do it? Is it possible to do in data step? Everything I tried give me a null result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a date *informat* like `date9.` using the `input` function.

```
data want;
    date='31DEC2015';
    format sas_date date9.;
    sas_date = input(date, date9.);
run;
```